# strapi does not save admin and content info when cloning repo

Tags: git, github, server, strapi, git-clone

This might be a bit stupid question but I am working on a full stack web app with Strapi and React. I created the project with quickstart on my pc and published the whole thing on a git repo. Now, I have cloned the repo on my laptop and also created the .env file with app keys required for strapi server.

When I run `yarn run strapi develop --watch-admin` on my laptop the server starts successfully but strapi asks me to create a new admin instead of a login page with my already existing admin info. I don't understand what is going wrong here, is it possible to save the server database information in the project with a vcs like github when I am only running the project server locally and have not deployed it?

Answer (score 2):

I got it!

What was going wrong is that my database was stored in the `.tmp` folder which by default did not get chucked into GitHub. I copied the `.tmp` folder from my pc where project was initiated and replaced it with `.tmp` folder in the cloned repo on my laptop. Now it works!